# Lookup Column headings and return corresponding column value in another row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I would like to create a formula that will look across columns for a particular value in the headings, and then return a corresponding row value within that same column. I think this is best explained with an illustration and example:

In this example, Column **BD** would be used to find all the values that have **OA.5** as the Column heading, and then output the corresponding value(s) from the current row for those column(s), separated by a comma. The Heading values may occur different amount of occurences within the ranges, and but in any of the column positions.

I uploaded a sample excel file at https://fastupload.io/rIDotkQSJgOIcEa/file of this that I highlighted the column in Blue that I want to add a formula to for this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What about this:  https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-index-match-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell/  You would just need to tweak it to fit your needs, but it should contain everything you need to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Is "OA.5" in the column still in accordance with the picture, is there any possibility of change/increase?